# Should we have a [functions] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are currently [7 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) that have the [functions] tag.

Is this a tag we want to keep? Would anyone ever want to highlight or ignore all questions tagged [functions], or subscribe to its RSS feed so that they can be quickly notified of new questions about functions?
When you see a question tagged [functions], under what circumstances could that give you any additional information about the question?
What other reasons might there be for wanting to keep [functions] as a tag?

If we don't want a [functions] tag, is there some other tag that it makes sense to set as a synonym? (So that all functions questions would automatically be tagged as this instead?)

Comment: what would be its function?

Answer (score 4):

Tag `functions` looks useless to me — let's just delete it. As for the last question in the list, maybe we should use something like `functional-equation`.

Comment: +1 Agreed. Such a tag is far too vague and could refer to anything.

Comment: This was my thought as well. I mostly wanted to see if anyone disagreed and thought it could be useful.

Comment: The tag "functions" may be useful for grouping results on functions that are not functional equations, e.g. Γ(x+y)>=Γ(x)+Γ(y) for x,y>=2 [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305/is-the-gamma-function-superadditive%5D] (but I am not quite sure on what a functional-equation tag would include).

Comment: In the meantime there are over 500 question tagged [tag:functions]. I think that the tagged should be kept, but it should be clarified when it is appropriate and when not - see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/about-functions-tag