# How to discourage users from using the "functions" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

The following is the [tag info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/functions/info) for the [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) tags:

> In mathematics, a function is a relation between a set of inputs and a set of permissible outputs with the property that each input is related to exactly one output. 
>   A function is defined by its set of inputs, called the domain; a set containing the set of outputs, and possibly additional elements, as members, called its codomain ; and the set of all input-output pairs, called its graph. Sometimes the codomain is called the function's *range*, but more commonly the word "range" is used to mean, instead, specifically the set of outputs (also called the image of the function). For example, we could define a function using the rule $f(x) = x^2$ by saying that the domain and codomain are the real numbers, and that the graph consists of all pairs of real numbers $(x, x^2)$.

In 2010 the tags [emerged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/715/should-we-have-a-functions-tag?noredirect=1&lq=1) and it is suggested to be deleted. Seems nothing had been done. There were [around 500 questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/715/should-we-have-a-functions-tag#comment12609_716) tagged with "functions" in 2011. Now in 2018, we have over 19,000 questions tagged with "functions".

Probably we all know why: whenever a question involves functions, people add the "functions" tag.

Not only that this is not what the tag info suggested, but also it makes the tag useless.

My questions is: How can we discourage people from using the "function" tag?

This is what I have in mind:

- Add to the tag info that one should not use the tag simply because you used functions in the questions (But really, who will read the tag info before using the tag?)
- Change the name from function to **mapping**. (Not sure how it can be done).

Comment: I agree - the functions tag is useless and way too broad. Basically every question could be tagged that.

Comment: Does having it as a tag even contribute anything at all? The only usage I can see other than "this question has a function in it" is when the questuon specifically relates to the *function-ness* of a function, which may be better served by something like a "well-defined" tag.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I have made a suggestion about what should be in the functions tag some time ago: [About (functions) tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3323). Other than one comment, nobody participated in that discussion - and the answer with the proposal got to score +1, which doesn't really count as consensus.

Comment: To add som specific examples, I would consider the question listed here as reasonable candidates for the (functions) tag: [Overview of basic results about images and preimages](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/359693). Similarly, the typical questions about properties of injective/surjective/bijective functions.

Comment: There are currently 3294 questions with *only* the [functions] tag. This is quite an immense effort to retag them and blacklist the tag entirely.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: The question you linked probably include most of the questions types that should be tagged "functions", if not all. If used correctly I guess there should not be more than 1k such questions, dupicates included.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's why I hesitated to suggest blacklisting the tag.

Comment: John, in the past with blacklisted the [homework] tag. I don't remember the exact number, but there were a lot of questions which had only that as a tag. After it was clear the consensus was to blacklist, a massive effort was undertaken to fix these questions, and then the blacklist happened. So first we need to discuss, in a certain urgent immediacy, whether or not this tag should be phased out entirely.

Comment: @AsafKaragila [This post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what/16426#16426) mentions *a few hundreds* of questions with *only* (homework) tag.

Comment: @Martin: I see. Well. I guess we have our work cut out for us. So first let's poll for some more input from the community about blacklisting.

Comment: I am not sure if we will have a majority decision on that. I think it is clear this tag are misused everyday, but some questions could be tagged "functions", as Martin suggested. In the mean time I will try to re-tag/close/delete some questions with that tags slowly.

Comment: This is why I said we first need to poll for more opinions. I flagged for moderator attention to add a [featured] tag to increase visibility. I hope this will be done.

Comment: While I agree that there is a certain class of questions that could benefit from being tagged [functions], I'm not sure how much benefit there is to this that would not already be gained by tagging them with [elementary-set-theory].  And as long as the [functions] tag exists, it's going to be abused a lot.

Comment: What about renaming it to "function-properties"? It's certainly more specific than "functions" and probably wouldn't be applied to anything with a function in it.

Comment: Let me also mentions the (somewhat related) "analysis" tags, where it is unclear and the tag info are changed. Discussion [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/should-the-analysis-tag-be-deprecated) and decision [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/why-is-the-tag-analysis-useful).

Comment: @JohnMa With all due respect to your cause, but I just happened to notice your un-tags on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2640978/find-f-if-ffx-ax2bxc) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641438/how-can-a-bijection-from-mathbb-rn-to-mathbb-r-exist-when-a-non-square-mat), which I believe both qualify for the `function` tag as currently defined.

Comment: @dxiv: for the first one, it seems [functional equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-equations) is a more suitable tag. Indeed there are quite a lot of similar questions with that tags (and without the functions tag). For the second one, probably I re-tag it too fast. I would have kept the functions tag, but adding the "elementary set theorey" tags might also be essential, since some of the above comments suggest deleting the tags.

Comment: @JohnMa Thank you for the followup. About the first one, [fractional iterates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Fractional_iterates_and_flows,_and_negative_iterates) are a lot more specific than `functional equations` at large IMHO. And the answer in that particular case depends precisely on the very basic function definition of "*domain*", so I still think that the `function` tag was/is appropriate.

Comment: @dxiv My understanding is that when study these functional equations, one inevitably has to deal with the domain of definition of your function. This is implicit in the study and I think the "functional equations" tag is good enough for that. Similar for (e.g.) some questions in differential equations (blow up of solutions), complex variables (branch cuts).

Comment: @AsafKaragila When looking at some old questions with only "functions" tags, I find your struggle [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143981/several-products-on-function-spaces-in-particular-the-product-f-g-x-to-y).

Comment: I think that some polling answers should be posted, perhaps. It would help to get some actual feedback from the community. So far all we have is a bunch of comments and very little active participation as far as discussions go.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think so. Do you want to post the answers? Or I can do that (and you are welcome to edit of course).

Comment: Just go for it...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Done.

Comment: Usage of a function is common /understood/implied. So, what appears to me 1)  Tag info could be shortened to include mappings 2) diamond moderators can time to time delete this tag (mis) usage. 3) Depending on how often this deletion appears to be needed, perhaps moderators can consider its deletion from tags list altogether  and tag to *functional analysis* as and when required in particular cases.

Comment: 2) I don't think moderators are responsible for that. Moreover, if such a measure is needed, probably stronger measure has to be done on the tag itself. 3) Most of the question wrongly tagged as "functions" are not from "functional analysis". @Narasimham

Comment: The description of the function tag should not just be a definition of "function." The description of a tag should be what the tag is for, not a definition. Doubt that would help solve the problem of misuse of the tag, since most posters don't read the description, I'd guess.

Answer (score 22):

> The name of the "functions" tag should be changed.

We could change it to "mapping", or "functions-properties" as suggested.

Quoting [celtschk](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27838/how-to-discourage-users-from-using-the-functions-tag/27883#comment113266_27838): It's certainly more specific than "functions" and probably wouldn't be applied to anything with a function in it.

This should also be implemented quite easily. It is not completely clear how effectively it could be though. We might also needs to go back to the existing 19000 questions to see if the new name are suitable for them.

Comment: BTW, my suggestion was "function-properties", not "functions-properties".

Answer (score 16):

> We should blacklist the "functions" tag.

Just like what we did for homework. In paricular, this means [similarly](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16337/99914) that we will request the SE team to completely remove the tag from the system and ensure that it cannot be re-created. This will result in a large number (at present over 3200) of untagged questions, which will be the responsibility of the community to fix.

If the problem is the existence of the tag itself, blacklisting would completely solve the problem.

However, as suggested in the [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27838/how-to-discourage-users-from-using-the-functions-tag/27884#comment113244_27838), there are some questions that "functions" serves as an suitable tag. And after trying to retag some questions in the tag, the retagging work is not completely trivial.

Answer (score 3):

> The "functions" tag should be deprecated.

We should add in the tag wiki that users should use a more specific tag, like "[algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) or [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory). This is similar to what we did on "[analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/analysis/info)" tag, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/why-is-the-tag-analysis-useful?noredirect=1&lq=1).

One advantage is that it can be implemented easily. The disadvantage is, obviously, that it is not so effective. There are more than 240000 questions tagged with "analysis", and around 100 new questions tagged with "analysis" every week. The [tag info page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/analysis/info) shows that the page has only around 400 views.

Comment: This is not a great solution. To some extent, the [tag:discrete-mathematics] was "deprecated", and it is still alive and kicking. If the [tag:functions] tag is so bad, I'd rather put the effort into retagging and blacklisting, with the option of creating new tags to compensate for that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest extending `functions` with the specific self-describing names that the tags might apply to. The extensions serve to more appropriately label the space to a degree whose efficacy varies directly with the propriety of the tags. I suggest prepending the word `function` to tags that might want to specify so that users may explore the space of tags through autocomplete. This might lead to better questions.